# Partition data into two separate groups s.t. residual sum of squares with one continuous predictor is minimized

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, grouping, partitioning

What's the basic algorithm to partition a set of data into two groups s.t. the sum of the two separate residual sum of squares is minimized? For example, consider the code below. Basically, how do you compute the value stored in `best.cutpoint$RSS` without iteratively testing each possible value?

```
set.seed(1)
ind.var <- runif(1000, 1, 50000)
dep.var <- ind.var * runif(1000, 2, 3) + rnorm(1000, 100, 500)

dat <- data.frame(ind.var, dep.var)

best.cutpoint <- list(RSS = Inf, cutpoint = NA)
for(cutpoint in sort(unique(ind.var))){
    # partition data
    dat1 <- dat[dat$ind.var > cutpoint,]
    dat2 <- dat[!(dat$ind.var > cutpoint),]

    if(nrow(dat1) < 2 | nrow(dat2) < 2){
        next
    }
    # estimate
    mod1 <- lm(dep.var ~ ind.var, dat = dat1)
    mod2 <- lm(dep.var ~ ind.var, dat = dat2)

    # calculate RSS
    part1.RSS <- sum((dat1$dep.var - (mod1$coefficients['(Intercept)'] + dat1$ind.var * mod1$coefficients['ind.var'])) ^ 2)
    part2.RSS <- sum((dat2$dep.var - (mod2$coefficients['(Intercept)'] + dat2$ind.var * mod2$coefficients['ind.var'])) ^ 2)

    total <- part1.RSS + part2.RSS

    if(total < best.cutpoint$RSS){
        best.cutpoint <- list(RSS = total, cutpoint = cutpoint)
    }
}
```

Which generates the following results from the following range of possible values.

```
> print(best.cutpoint)
$RSS
[1] 75241532557

$cutpoint
[1] 34351.46

> range(dat$ind.var)
[1]    66.73151 49996.52975
```

Comment: This would seem to be an effort to reinvent regression and discriminant analysis. Doing it with an iterative solution is amusing but suggest that you do not know basic statistics. There is a one step matrix solution.

Comment: are you trying to classify something? what does your `dep.var` look like? I guess I'm confused by this part -- "partition a set of data into two groups s.t. the sum of the two separate residual sum of squares is minimized". So you're saying you want to fit two models on one dataset where your outcome is continuous and to find the best breakpoint?

Comment: BondedDust: So what is this basic solution? That'd be very helpful. 

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you'd want a segmented or piecewise regression? you can check out this package for more information http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-for-ecologists-putting-together-a-piecewise-regression/ http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/segmented.pdf; if you're trying to classify the LDA/logit/whatever is fine.

Comment: the more i read this question, the more i think you want a segmented regression with a breakpoint. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/segmented.pdf check the documentation here.

Comment: The 'dep.var' is continuous. Basically, I mean split the data into two separate groups s.t. the sum of the two separate sum of squared residuals is minimized.

Comment: i'm writing an answer now, i think it'll help

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC appears to be solving a related problem - and for that matter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering. However neither of them guarantee to find the absolute global best fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're asking how to determine a breakpoint for a [segmented or piecewise linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression). Let me know if that's not the case.

The package is useful for this purpose [Segmented](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/segmented.pdf)

First let's genrate some data:

```
x<-seq(1:20)
y<-c(seq(1:10),seq(10,100,by=10))
plot(x,y)
```

This data looks like,

[image]

It's pretty obvious where the "breakpoint" is.

Next, let's fit a model with the segmented package:

```
library(segmented)
lin.mod <- lm(y~x)
segmented.mod <- segmented(lin.mod, seg.Z = ~x, psi=14)
```

Did it find the breakpoint?

```
plot(segmented.mod)
points(x,y)
```

[image]

It looks like it did.

```
> segmented.mod
Call: segmented.lm(obj = lin.mod, seg.Z = ~x, psi = 14)

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
(Intercept)            x         U1.x  
     0.1818       0.9545       9.0455  

Estimated Break-Point(s) psi1.x : 11.08
```

Where seg.z and psi are defined as:

```
seg.Z a formula with no response variable, such as seg.Z=~x1+x2, indicating the
(continuous) explanatory variables having segmented relationships with the response.
Currently, formulas involving functions, such as seg.Z=~log(x1) or
seg.Z=~sqrt(x1), or selection operators, such as seg.Z=~d[,"x1"] or seg.Z=~d$x1,
are not allowed.
psi named list of vectors. The names have to match the variables of the seg.Z
argument. Each vector includes starting values for the break-point(s) for the
corresponding variable in seg.Z. If seg.Z includes only a variable, psi may be
a numeric vector. A NA value means that ‘K’ quantiles (or equally spaced values)
are used as starting values; K is fixed via the seg.control auxiliary function.
```